# Search engine crawlers get redirected to English pages (and thus avoid other languages' pages) with a multilingual website

Tags: php, redirect, cookies, web-crawler, multilingual

I have the following multilingual URL structure:

```
example.com/article123            # english
example.com/fr/article123         # french
example.com/de/article123         # german
```

There is an automatic 302 redirection to the relevant language, according to the browser language (`$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`). This is good for user experience, because most users haven't to manually click on a language switcher. According to my statistics, it works well.

**Problem**: when using Ahrefs Website Audit tool (it will be the same for search engine crawlers, GoogleBot, ...), I see that **their crawlers get 302-redirected and therefore never visit the french website**.

Indeed when the crawler (probably set to english) visits `example.com/fr/article123` it will be redirected to `example.com/article123`. I imagine that these crawlers don't take cookies in consideration, so it will be the same for all pages.

**What techical solution should I use to avoid a multilingual website to be crawled incorrectly by search engine bots?**

TL;DR: How could I trigger a redirection according to the browser language for a normal user, and **not redirect** bots (such as GoogleBot, Facebook or Twitter Crawlers that are responsible for the "Share..." displayed cards)?

This is what I use:

```
function lang_redirect() {  
    if (isset($_COOKIE['lang_redirect']))  // already redirected in the last 24 hours, don't do it again
        return;
    global $lang, $requesturi;
    $browserlang = getlang($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);   // fr, de, en...
    $link = lang_translation_link($browserlang);
    if (($browserlang != $lang) && ($link != ''))
        header("Location: " . $link);      // redirect now!
    header("Set-Cookie: lang_redirect=1; Max-Age=86400; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax");  
}
```

---

Note: The redirection happens **only once** (by setting cookies), because a visitor with a browser set to german *could* want to visit the english website and not be redirected *every time* to the german website. Example:

```
example.com/article123          # browser set to german
=> example.com/de/article123    # automatic redirection, setting a cookie to not redirect anymore
example.com/article123          # user returns on english website
=> no redirection here because there has already been a first redirection
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove your system that automatically redirects based on `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`.  It makes your site uncrawlable by search engines and it it is bad for user experience.

Instead of automatically redirecting, you can put a prominent notice in the page that says:

> Your browser says that you prefer English.  Would you like to visit the English version of the page now?
>
> [Switch to English]

For more information see [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization) which has a whole section on why redirection with the accept-language-header kills SEO.

Comment: Yes and no. Many multilang WP plugins (such as Polylang and WPML if I remember correctly) have this automatic redirect feature (only *once* a day as mentioned at the end of my question) and they are search-engine-crawler-friendly. How to achieve both search-engine-crawler-friendliness and automatic redirection according to browser language? It is possible because some plugins do this. Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe that these plugins have such a redirect feature.    For example WPML doesn't redirect on their own site: `$ curl --head --header 'Accept-Language: en' https://wpml.org/es/caracteristicas/
HTTP/2 200 `  Polylang doesn't have a list of example sites where I could test one that I could find, nor is their site available in other languages that I see.

Comment: I did have a site using WPML years ago, and I confirmed 100% it had this feature (see [here](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/automatic-redirect-based-on-browser-language/) for the feature). I remember the Google indexing of both languages was perfect though.

Comment: That page says that they implemented the redirects in JavaScript to prevent Google from seeing them but that since 2015 Google executes JavaScript and the redirects are now problematic for SEO.  Here is there full post about it: https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/automatic-redirect-based-on-browser-language/how-browser-language-redirect-affects-google-indexing/

Comment: Yes that's right. According to my experience from 2016-19 it worked fine on my website with auto redirect enabled based on browser language. Maybe the difference is that in this WP plugin, they redirect with *Javascript* and so GoogleBot sees both versions and understands they are localized, and takes both in consideration ... whereas my current solution is a PHP `header("Location...")` redirection which is done at a "lower level", and so GoogleBot skips the original page before redirection. Maybe I should switch to a 100% JS solution? What do you think?

Comment: I think you should stop auto-redirecting.   I've done internationalized sites with the "switch language" dialog and found it to be a much better solution.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Stephen. I'll think about this during a while, and then I'll maybe choose your solution :)

Comment: I just tried something @StephenOstermiller: redirect with JavaScript and not PHP `header('Location /')`.  Something like `<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='...newlink...', 10);</script>`. It "seems" to work: at least in Ahrefs audit tool, even if I select "Execute Javascript", these pages are now indexed as "Status 200" and not "302 Redirection". Let's see if GoogleBot thinks the same :) I'll have a look in GoogleSearchConsole. Any idea about this technique?

Comment: Google only executes the page for like five or six seconds I believe so 10 seconds should be fine for Google as well. However redirecting the page after 10 seconds is far from ideal for users.